# Why is my image disappearing in landscape mode?

Tags: android, imageview, landscape-portrait

I have an image in portrait mode, which is displayed correctly. When I change the configuration to landscape, the image is not displayed.

Note that the `LinearLayout`, enclosing the `ImageView` is displayed right(I checked it by changing the background). But when I changed the background for the `ImageView`, the background was also not shown.

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_weight="3">
           <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:minHeight="48dp" android:minWidth="48dp" android:src="@drawable/xyz" android:id="@+id/img"/>
```

Comment: Add your layout xml to your answer.

Comment: I guess due to your weight property.. I know its neccesary.. probably in landscape mode your linearlayout is not getting proper space of the screen to display the image hence its hiding the image.

Comment: But I see the border of the linearLayout within the landscape screen as well. I put a different color to the linearlayout and can see the layout border.

Comment: Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, [your layout file](http://pastebin.com/yjFMKpEW) is unnecessarily large and complex. So let's try a couple of things-

First, try creating a simple version of your XML file that contains the barebones for displaying the image. If that works in both portrait and landscape, you know that the problem is not your activity or your image.

If the first step works, the next step would be to work on simplifying your layout file, there is a lot that could be pruned. It goes seven layers deep at points, that should almost never happen. [Here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) is a good blog post by an Android engineer on better layout design. You can find similar resources elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different files specified for portrait and landscape more? I.e., do you have a layout file with the same name in the layout folder as well as the layout-land folder? If so, make sure both files include the ImageView.

Comment: The landscape has not been considered separately, and is due for work. Currently, using the same image in "layout" for both and portrait and landscape mode. Note that only this image is not visible in landscape and the other images are shown in both portrait and landscape.

Comment: You haven't specified- do you have a layout file in the layout-land folder or not? Edit your original post and include the layout file(s).

Comment: Edited the question with the layout. I don't have a layout-land folder separately.

Comment: Is that the entire layout? It doesn't even have a closing tag </LinearLayout>

Comment: The closing tag is not being included in the post, for some reason. The entire layout also could not be added, maybe due to the size.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely specifying the file you want to display like

```
myImageView.setImage("myfile.jpg");
```

in your `onCreate` method.

Move this code to `onResume` (create `onResume` with the `@Override` if you do not already have it)  This will fix your problem

Comment: The image src is specified in the xml layout file.