# Changing background image based on orientation.

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I have a simple problem that seems to have two simple solutions, neither of which work for me and i cant seem to understand why.

I want to have a portrait view background and an alternate landscape background for my layout. I placed the different images in the separate folders layout and layout-land respectively.

portrait = exactly what it should
landscape = black screen

then i tried making a folder called drawable-land and placing the wide view background there. 
same result.

black when going to portrait.

Is there something im missing? This seems so simple and i cant understand what i could possibly be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To programmatically change your background depending on the orientation of the screen:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
     Resources res = getResources();
     Drawable portrait = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.portrait);
     Drawable landscape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.landscape);

     WindowManager window = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
     Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
     int num = display.getRotation();
     if (num == 0){
         linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(portrait);
     }else if (num == 1 || num == 3){
         linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(landscape);
     }else{
        linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(portrait);
     }
    }
```

Try that out, I hope it helps!

Comment: Coding it now...waiting for it to build. FC'd the first time, i think because i left the "android:background attribute set in the XML Thanks for the quick response either way!

Comment: Nope FC'd again. Maybe because the pics are still in drawable-port and drawable-land? Obviously i still declared them in the java but thats all i can think of...

Comment: Ok, so changed the local so both are in the Drawable Folder and now i am back to getting the black screen on landscape mode.....could the landscape image be too big or something?

Comment: How large is the image file and whats the layout? Also, see if [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497064/why-is-my-image-disappearing-in-landscape-mode) helps

Comment: Logcat says Bitmap is too large...Changing that next

Comment: Yea, that's most likely the problem. Each device only gets a certain amount of memory for each app, so, if the file is too large you will get an error. Though, I'm surprised it didn't force close on you rather than just appear blank.

Comment: Yup Bingo. works great now. And might i say, so nice to get someone who didnt mind punching out some code to help me...easily my biggest frustration coming here is everyone is so over my head with answers..code is much easier to follow. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Drawable Image handling based on Orientation is easy without doing any extra code.
Just we need to follow few drawable directory naming structure and put images accordingly.
I think, This link will help a lot: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

**Thank you for the the Accepted Answer provided by chRyNan** , It did work for me without any hitch . As Constraint Layout is the Default Layout now and setBackGroundDrawable is  deprecated . here is another version for 2018.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_organization_key_enter);

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable portrait = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.portrait);
    Drawable landscape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.landscape);

    WindowManager window = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
    int num = display.getRotation();
    if (num == 0){
        constraintLayout.setBackground(portrait);
    }else if (num == 1 || num == 3){
        constraintLayout.setBackground(landscape);
    }else{
        constraintLayout.setBackground(portrait);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the two image files have the same name, even though the files contain different images. For example, if you have an image named 'background01.png' in both the drawable-land and drawable-port folders, the following will work:

```
   <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background01" />
```